# Error Number: 1064 when select from database

Tags: mysql, sql

when select images from a database below error is shown & after i delete record in the database its remain the same number inside (id)

this is the error

```
 Error Number: 1064 

 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
 server version for the right syntax to use near '16,19,1,2,1,2,1 )' at line 1

 select * from images where id in(,16,19,1,2,1,2,1 )

 Filename: controllers/Admin.php

 Line Number: 1046
```

and this is select statment :

```
if (!empty($data->images)) {
            $qry = $this->db->query("select * from images where id in($data- 
>images )");
            $res['results'] = $qry->result();
        }
```

and now my database is empty and this error still remaining ?

Comment: The error message itself says that this is **MySQL** - not SQL Server - removed wrong tag, added `mysql` instead

Comment: It looks like your parameter source has a leading comma.

Comment: Commas. Carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the leading comma. like this.

```
select * from images where id in( 16,19,1,2,1,2,1 )
```

there is a leading comma in `$data->images`

Comment: ```(, 16, 19, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 ) ``` see before 16

Comment: oki i see but in the code how can i find these numbers ?? there is no numbers in ana select statment like this

Comment: if it is a string u can use  ```trim( $data->images,  ' , '  )```  . it will remove any leading comma

Comment: used it before select statment but nothing change

Comment: if (!empty($data->images)) {
                trim( $data->images, ' , ' );
                $qry = $this->db->query("select * from images where id in($data->images) ");
                $res['results'] = $qry->result();
            }

Comment: you are not assigning trimmed variable. 
 ```$data->images =  trim( $data->images, ' , ' );``` it will be like this